# ConcurrentHashMap updated values not reflecting in another thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

I am adding values in ConcurrentHashMap by main thread. While trying to access the ConcurrentHashMap from another thread it's always returning empty list.

I am sure the values are updated by main thread.

Here is my code

```
public abstract class Foo1<K> implements Foo {

    ...
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<K, String> keyToRequestMapping = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


    @Override
    public AttributeSet get(String request) {

        //Some logic
        ...

        keyToRequestMapping.put(key, request);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = REFRESH_WINDOW_SECONDS, initialDelay = 0, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public synchronized void runPeriodicUpdateForCache() {

        Set<K> key_set = keyToRequestMapping.keySet();
        Iterator<K> itr = key_set.iterator();

        log.debug("ketToRequestMapping keys {}", key_set); // Logging empty lis
        ....
    }
}
```

This Food1 class in extended

```
@Component
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class FooImpl extends Foo1<String> {


    public static synchronized FooImpl getInstance() {
        return StaticApplicationContext.getContext().getBean(FooImpl.class);
    }

    public FooImpl() {
        super(configStoreKey, getResponseAttributes());
    }

    @Override
    public String getCacheKey(AttributeSet request) {
        return request.get("ABC");
    }

}


// Usage

FooImpl.getInstance()get(request);
```

Unable to understand what's wrong with this.. also tried to remove `synchronized` from `runPeriodicUpdateForCache` function but no luck.
I also tried to make keyToRequestMapping `volatile` but result was same.
Not able to understand why I am getting the empty list.

Comment: How are you calling get() here? What annotations are used for Foo1<K> ?

Comment: @Mukti09 Foo1 is inherited by a class let say `FooImpl`, I am add those details in question